# ECB PSPP bond purchase program

Tags: fixed-income

Can someone please explain why the net purchases done by the ECB for certain months are negative for certain countries ?

I thought the ECB only buys bonds no ?

Comment: Probably due to bond redemptions. Do you have link to the statistics?

Comment: Yes, https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/implement/app/html/index.en.html#pspp if you go to PSPP data you'll see negative values for certain months. can you please care to explain what you mean by bond redemptions ?

Comment: They probably didn't sell but rather for some months the bond holdings were reduced due to bonds maturing.